# What happens with previous HTML page after users navigate away from it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, navigation

Assumes I have two HTML pages, let call them page1.html and page2.html. And then users navigate from page1.html to page2.html by made a call to assign or replace method of location object. I have some questions as below:

Q1: What happens with the DOM tree of the page1.html, will it be unloaded and reloads latter when we navigate back to it from the page2.html? Can I reference DOM tree of the page1.html from page2.html?

Q2: If I’m maintaining a socket connection in a socket object in the page1.html, can I pass that socket object to page2.html? Can I listen for events of that socket object in page2.html?

Q3: Can I have a common object of both page1.html and page2.html. And I can do something like maintaining a timer to do common task for both page1.html and page2.html in that object? This object is like singleton object in other OOP language.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do any of these things. It's a brand-new page, with its own DOM and Javascript environment, the old one will be unloaded/destroyed, and the only way to communicate would be passing data through the query, localStorage or something like that (which is obviously very limited).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043674/how-to-keep-an-array-after-navigation-away-to-another-page?rq=1

Comment: People used to use iframes as a "sticky container" to work around this problem. Not so much anymore, I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: What happens with the DOM tree of the page1.html, will it be unloaded and reloads latter when we navigate back to it from the page2.html?

More or less. Browsers cache previously visited pages and probably won't fire a new load event when revisited using "back" navigation. Some will keep the page in its previous state, some wont.

> Can I reference DOM tree of the page1.html from page2.html?

No. From a DOM point of view, *page1.html* has ceased to exist.

> Q2: If I’m maintaining a socket connection in a socket object in the page1.html, can I pass that socket object to page2.html?

No, but you may be able to serialise it when *page1* closes, send it to the server, then include it in *page2* where it can be restored (*cf* JSON).

> Can I listen for events of that socket object in page2.html?

Not if it's still in *page1*, but you may be able to emulate that behaviour on the server.

> Q3: Can I have a common object of both page1.html and page2.html.

Not using javascript. However, if you passed the object to *page2* (say via serialisation or some other method via the server) then you can perhaps pass it back again.

> And I can do something like maintaining a timer to do common task for both page1.html and page2.html in that object?

No, but again you can do such stuff server side.

> This object is like singleton object in other OOP language.

Cool.

If you describe what you are actually trying to do (i.e. the outcome you are trying to achieve rather then the method you are using to do it), a suitable architecture or design pattern might be suggested, e.g. as Abhi has intimated, a one page application may suit.

Comment: Thank you! I'm developing an application for Samsung Gear device and I want to keep the socket connection between mobile device and the Gear device somewhere so that I can know whenever there is a new message from mobile device. (You can think about mobile device is server side and Gear device is client side in client-server architecture). I also think may be the one-page application is suitable for my application. Can you please give me tutorials about that topic? Thank you so much!